# Disable a link possible in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to disable a link and route. Is it possible? i.e

```
 $route['test/admin'] = 'admin';
```

myproject.com/test/admin now going to myproject.com/admin, this is ok. But still myproject.com/admin link is working.

What i have need that disable the link so that no one can access through this link myproject.com/admin

Comment: Have you tried `$route['admin'] = '/';` like @ris said?

Comment: yes, its not working because there are many methods in Admin controller and its redirect all admin/method to default controller

Comment: so whenver a user goes to `myproject.com/admin` you dont want it to work correct? what should the user see when they go to that URL?

Comment: @CodeGodie, I want to stop access through this link myproject.com/admin
User will see error page or something else when go to this link

Comment: but... you are saying that you still have methods there. If you want to route this to an error page how are you trying to access these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check manual and redirect user or show error on `Admin` class/file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if($this->uri->segment(1) == "admin")
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: hi, @ Bora 
There are many other methods in "Admin" controller. So this will stop working for other methods

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I'm not a wizard! I just show alternative methods. This does not require downvote the answer. This is only about your low quality question. I'm done!

Comment: Hi, @Bora I do not downvote to you. I just remove the answers as "solved". Don't know about whether its count as a downvote. sorry

Comment: @RejoanulAlam You said that `other methods`? It is ajax requests?

Comment: No these are normal methods. Probably i can't clear my requirements.
**I need to stop the admin link for security and change the link as unknown link**

Comment: @RejoanulAlam My codes should be right! Because above codes prevent to access only first segment is `admin` like `domain.com/admin`. But  `domain.com/test/admin` link should work perfect. I guess, i couldnt understand what you need exactly, sorry.

Comment: yes, it was my fault. last quick question
How may i merge several routes. such as
 `$route['test/admin'] = 'admin'`
 `$route['test/admin/logout'] = 'admin/logout'`
etc

Answer (score 1):

you can route your admin to somewhere else like

```
$route['admin'] = '/';
```

or any other page

Comment: There are many other methods in "Admin" controller. So this will stop working for other methods

Comment: i think if you want to access other method the url will look like admin/somemethod . so it will not affect those url . only the index method will disable .

Answer (score 0):

Make redirection in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect /admin http://www.yourproject.com/test/admin
```

Comment: this will not solve the problem. I want to hide/disable the admin link

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is expected behavior when someone type `http://www.yourproject.com/admin` in your oppinion? What should be than?

Comment: yes, my question was unclear.
**I need to stop the admin link for security and change the link as unknown link**
like change `http://www.yourproject.com/admin` this to something like this `http://www.yourproject.com/unknown/admin`

Comment: Now we've got unknown uri segment just to be *easier* to guess what's your request goal? Nice. With no further explanation your request or at least programming pragmatism doesn't much sense. You have pretty fair amount of right answer to initial question.